# Vue: How to test dynamic components import?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs

I have this simple Vue SFC which renders the component given the prop value.

```html
<template>
  <component :is="component" v-bind="stepProps" />
</template>

<script>
import { _ } from 'core'

export default {
  name: 'SetupFlow',
  props: {
    type: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    step: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    stepProps: Object
  },
  computed: {
    component () {
      const camelCaseName = _.camelCase(this.step)
      const name = camelCaseName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + camelCaseName.slice(1)

      return () => import(`@/components/ProfileSetup/GMB/${name}`)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

In my test, I just need to make sure that the component imported is being rendered. Here is my test file so far:

```js
import { createLocalVue, shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import SetupFlow from '@/components/ProfileSetup/SetupFlow'

const localVue = createLocalVue()

describe('SetupFlow.vue', () => {
  let propsData
  let stubs

  beforeEach(() => {
    propsData = {
      type: 'GMB',
      step: 'step-example' // this file does not exist, so I need to mock `import`
    }
  })

  it('renders the given step component', async () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(SetupFlow, { localVue, propsData })
  })
})
```

This is an error I get when running the test:
[image: Test error]

Any ideas how to mock `import` so that `step-example` returns a mock vue component?